# Content running into alignparentbottom

Tags: android, android-layout

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24856/android_issue.PNG

i have a text view on top running into the relative layout with two nested buttons on the bottom. i tried putting margin bottom on the top element and then margin top and the android:layout_alignParentBottom element but it didn't change the fact that the text ran into the buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide the layout file so here is a small example on how to avoid that issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i had one parent scrollview so instead i made the parent view a relativelayout and put a scrollview in with my main content and below the scrollview was another relative  view with the buttons -- thanks!